# How does google indexes text documents?

Tags: indexing, search-engine, elastic-search

Unfortunately, I didn't find much information surrounding this, no pdfs, no textbooks that discuss this in just enough detail. And I didn't see any forums posts about this. I just want to learn an example scenario of indexing in big data.

I've found this but I'd love some explanations and details about it rather than a picture alone.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. In general Google doesn't give the details of their methods, as a private company they don't want to and they don't have to. This picture gives a decent idea of what indexing basically looks like, but there are certainly a lot of tweaks to make things more accurate and more efficient. I'm not sure what kind of details you're looking for, is the concept of inverted index clear to you?

Comment: yeah it's somewhat clear to me. i don't want google's if they don't allow to tell,  but in general the indexing techniques purposed for any big data. lucene is an example of indexing tool, but i want to learn like this figure rather than how lucene coding is done. high level overview.

Comment: I don't feel confident enough to give a full answer, but the main idea is indeed simply storing the inverted index usually together with something like TFIDF. The main issue is efficient storage/access, which is more a problem related to distributed database than an NLP.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.